# How to resolve 'assert' error in a recursive CTE query on Amazon Redshift (using DataGrip as IDE)?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Using a recursive CTE in an Amazon Redshift query (recursive CTEs were recently introduced in April 2021 for Redshift I believe). Receiving an error message that I have never seen before and cannot track down a lead on Stack Overflow. For reference, I am using DataGrip as my query IDE. Key temp table query is below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS daily_gap_final;
CREATE TEMP TABLE daily_gap_final  DISTKEY (asin) as (
    with RECURSIVE daily_gap_final_calc (asin,calendar_day, assessment_period_start_date , assessment_period_end_date, gl_product_group,daily_forecast,day1_starting_inv,ending_inv,ending_inv_excluding_open_po, expected_net_flow,expected_qty_calc,rank) as (
    -- START WITH FIRST DAY OF DAILY GAP
    SELECT
        asin
        ,calendar_day
        , assessment_period_start_date
        , assessment_period_end_date
        ,gl_product_group
        ,daily_forecast
        ,day1_starting_inv
        ,greatest(day1_starting_inv + expected_net_flow,0)::numeric(18,8) as ending_inv
        ,greatest(day1_starting_inv - daily_forecast,0)::numeric(18,8) as ending_inv_excluding_open_po
        , expected_net_flow
        ,expected_qty_calc
        , 0 as rank
FROM daily_gap
    where calendar_day = assessment_period_start_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
         a.asin
        ,dateadd(day, 1, a.calendar_day) calendar_day
        , a.assessment_period_start_date
        , a.assessment_period_end_date
        ,b.gl_product_group
        ,b.daily_forecast
        ,b.day1_starting_inv
        ,greatest(a.ending_inv + b.expected_net_flow,0)::numeric(18,8) as ending_inv
        ,greatest(a.ending_inv_excluding_open_po - b.daily_forecast,0)::numeric(18,8) as ending_inv_excluding_open_po
        ,b.expected_net_flow
        ,b.expected_qty_calc
        ,a.rank + 1
    FROM daily_gap_final_calc a
    Left join daily_gap b on a.asin = b.asin and a.gl_product_group = b.gl_product_group and dateadd(day, 1, a.calendar_day) =b.calendar_day
    where dateadd(day, 1, a.calendar_day) <= b.assessment_period_end_date
)
    SELECT * FROM daily_gap_final_calc order by asin, calendar_day
    );
```

Error Message is as follows:

```
[2021-06-23 10:54:38] [XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Assert
[2021-06-23 10:54:38] Details:
[2021-06-23 10:54:38] -----------------------------------------------
[2021-06-23 10:54:38] error:  Assert
[2021-06-23 10:54:38] code:      1000
[2021-06-23 10:54:38] context:   new_refcnt >= 0 || (m_rowbuf == NULL && !m_was_shared) - Negative reference count only allowed for non-shared rowsets
[2021-06-23 10:54:38] query:     53275121
[2021-06-23 10:54:38] location:  disk_based_rowset.cpp:321
[2021-06-23 10:54:38] process:   query56_638_53275121 [pid=86424]
```

Please help if anyone has seen something like this before!